# Add dependency on a local swift package in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11, swift-package-manager

I am trying to add a dependency on a local swift package in my Xcode project. (I don't want to add a dependency using a file url `file://me/dev/app/package` as this cannot be shared to other environments)

I tried to drag & drop the package to the target. This creates a references to the package in the project that I was able to add in the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase, but the library is still not found.

```
No such module 'Analytics'
```

My original configuration

[image]

After drag & drop

[image]

and here is my package configuration:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Analytics",
    products: [
        .library(name: "Analytics", targets: ["Analytics"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(path: "../SomeOtherPackage"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "Analytics", dependencies: [
            "SomeOtherPackage",
        ]),
    ]
)
```

I've also included the Package in the target linked binaries and/or bundle resources and/or compiled sources to no avail:

[image]

I've read [this long discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-add-local-swift-package-as-dependency/26457) that doesn't seem to be conclusive.

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying: https://github.com/gsabran/SPM_Xcode_test

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is literally what I do and it just works... Xcode 11.2

I. Prepare package

1. File > New > Swift Package > Select Empty Folder (or create new) > Enter Library Name (MyLibrary)
2. Here in project find MyLibrary.swift and make public structure & variable, so there is some export to use in app (I made static constant and fixed UT)
3. Build > OK > Close Project

II. Prepare project

1. File > New > Project > iOS > Single View App > Enter Name (MyApp) > Next > Select Same Folder as above (it is by default) > Create
2. Build > OK
3. From Finder drag MyLibrary folder right below project name in Xcode Project Navigator
4. Build > OK
5. Click MyApp project icon in Project Navigator > Select MyApp application target > section Frameworks, Libraries, … click + > In topmost Workspace section select MyLibrary > Add
6. Clean > Build > OK
7. Open ContentView.swift > type `import MyLibrary` (autocompletion already see it)
   Replace “Hello, World” with "(MyLibrary.text)"
8. Build & Run > OK

That’s it.

To verify used relative path open project.pbxproj in TextEdit, here is screenshot

[image: Swift package relative path]

**Update:** 
*Note1* - I've considered some delay in package resolving after Clean, so during some period of time, 1-2 mins here, Build fails exactly with reported error, but after that delay it is visible that index restarted and following Build succeeded.
*Note2* - Adding second dependent package in graph (MyApp > MyLibrary > AnotherLibrary) is the same.

Comment: A good answer, thanks. I had to Quit Xcode after several of the steps, to get the library to appear as an option for Adding.

Comment: Also, this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/developing_a_swift_package_in_tandem_with_an_app

Comment: And this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/editing_a_package_dependency_as_a_local_package

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to specify a package as optional, similar to "Required" and "Optional" statuses in Build Phase -> Link Binbary with Libraries