# Cloned a Swift Package to alter it. Pasted local clone into Xcode. Can't access swift my project's classes from files within this package

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager

[image: xcode project file structure]

I can't access classes - e.g. public class Foo in ContentView.swift, from within JSBridge.swift

import Foo does not work.
And no 'target membership' panel on the right hand side of xcode displays for any JSBridge dir file (which prevents testing whether target membership is the issue).

How might I make my classes available to files within this JSBridge folder / JSBridge.swift file?

Edit:
I have this JSBridge dir in my build settings > compile sources. But there's still no 'target membership' panel when I click on any of the JSBridge files.

How do you make this dir/dir's files members of your target?

[image]

Comment: If your files are not members of a target, then they shouldn't even be compiled. Make them members of the right target.

Comment: I edited my answer w/ a pic to give more context. JSBridge dir is part of my compile sources - am I missing something that would make all JSBridge dir files members of my target?

Comment: You might find helpful topic [Add dependency on a local swift package in Xcode 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59183124/12299030)