# I can't import my swift package into a project

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I am working on a package that makes working with the Unsplash API simple. [Here it is.](https://github.com/ArnavMotwani/UnsplashSwiftUI)

My problem is that when I add it to my test project, it can't find the package in scope however it can find my other package just fine. I don't see this won't work (I can provide a throwaway api key if you want to test the UnsplashRandom module but right now the fact the package won't import is the problem)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UnsplashSwiftUI

struct UnsplashRandomTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        UnsplashRandom(clientId: "")
    }
}

struct UnsplashRandomTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UnsplashRandomTest()
    }
}
```

[image: The package has been added]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59183124/12299030?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package does not pass the build due to availability errors:

[image]

You need to specify the minimum deployment target for the iOS platform. (which I suppose you are interested in)

Since you are using API that is only available in **iOS 14** or newer, you can add the `platforms` parameter to `Package` initializer in your manifest file like so:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "UnsplashSwiftUI",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "UnsplashSwiftUI",
            targets: ["UnsplashSwiftUI"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "UnsplashSwiftUI",
            dependencies: []),
    ]
)
```

That fixed your issue.

Comment: Yep I realised, with the comment earlier, thanks!